# Redirect_to with post method and parametrs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

how to `redirect_to` user with **post** method and parameters ?

like this code:

```
redirect_to 'example.com?key=value&key=value' # with post method
```

Comment: You should search and research before posting a question on SO.  Take a look at [Before you ask](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before).

Comment: i searched but not found anything , and i want alternate method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect\_to using POST in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985596/redirect-to-using-post-in-rails)

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943169/rails-routes-how-to-pass-all-request-params-in-a-redirect